# How to calculate the gradient of a matrix

Tags: math, derivative, calculus

let f(x) = [2x^2, 3y^5]

I know how to calculate the derivative of f(x), which will be [d/dx 2x^2, d/dx 3y^5].

Is there a similar process being done when calculating the gradient of f(x)? If not, then how do you calculate the gradient of f(x)?

Comment: How is this a programming problem? If you add more context, including evidence of your work so far on the problem and a statement of just where you are stuck, this problem would be a better fit for the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I didn't know that. But how am I suppose to know the Mathematics Stack Exchange? Where does it say that there is an another website for Mathematics? I tried searching for website just like that.

Comment: There are several ways to find that site. I could show them to you, but it would be easier for you to just use the link in my comment. Well, here is one way: the tag for `math` specifically says to use the other site for general math questions--this site is for questions on both math and programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: Ok I understand. I will keep note of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient of a vector is a matrix

```
grad([f(x,y), g(x,y)]) = | df/dx   dg/dx |
                         |               |
                         | df/dy   dg/dy |
```